# Exported excel, percentage shown as date

Tags: excel

[Added screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PfNsf.png)

I have an exported excel file from a website which have column that supposed to show percentage. Many cells in the column shown as date, for example a cell has "26.45.00", and in the formula bar it's shown as "01/01/1900  02.45.00". Another cell has "29.04.00", but in the formula bar shown as "01/01/1900  05.04.00". How do I convert this value to percentage?

Edit2:
example: a cell display "49.59.00" but in the formula bar it's show as "02/01/1990 01.59.00". The original value should be "49.59%"

Comment: What should these percentages be? What's the original data look like?

Comment: example: a cell display "49.59.00" but in the formula bar it's show as "02/01/1990 01.59.00".  The original value should be "49.59%"

Answer (score 0):

1. It seems to me that the date "01/01/1900 02.45.00" that you are
   commenting is a number 01011900024500
2. And for some reason excel it's taking this as a date formatting it
   with next format "dd/mm/aaaa hh:mm:ss"
3. The meaning is dd=day mm=month aaaa=year hh=hour mm=minutes
   ss=seconds

Could you share a screenshot to see more details about this issue?.
Also it will be good to have the extension of the excel file to see if it is an .xls or .xlsx or .xlsm or .csv (to see the extension file, Right clic on the excel file->Properties->File Type).

Comment: Thanks for your response. Sorry, I' have no internet connection until now. I should add that when the file is being open excel displays message saying that the file format and extension don't match. But I can still open it. As for your question, the file type is Microsoft Excel 97-2003 Worksheet (.xls).

I'm new here I don't know how to add pics in the comment. So I edited my question to add screenshot you asked